# Триггер "курсор рядом"

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу стиль для контрола. Нужно, что бы если курсор был на контроле или рядом, а точнее слева в радиусе 10 пикселей, то были бы изменения параметров контрола.

Полагаю, что придётся писать реализацию получения позиции курсора и сравнивать её с позицией контрола+ширина+радиус, но можно ли сделать проще? Или вовсе всё реализовать в самом Xaml?

Comment: А сделать просто прозрачный задний фон с отступом на 10 пикселей и на него вешать событие не вариант?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ собирался именно так и делать, но у меня идёт панельный дизайн, и если я захочу сделать через прозрачный фон - нужно будет мутить костыли с размером соседних панелей и накладывать одну панель на другую, чего я делать совсем не желаю

Comment: Запускаем таймер, в его событии сравниваем позицию курсора и контролов. Конечно, постоянно работающий таймер - это быдлокодинг, зато просто.

Comment: Вариант EvgeniyZ в сочетании с отрицательным Margin должен помочь, но будут проблемы, думаю. Там что лучше ловить события перемещения мыши по окну и вычислять в коде.